# importing Chinese characters into MySQL via SSIS

Tags: mysql, ssis

I faced a problem when I try to import Chinese characters from Hive into MySQL via SSIS. The setting in SSIS is below
[image]

[image]

If I use the same setting to import into SQL server the data is correct. But when I change to MySQL then cannot show Chinese character. And if I write Python script to import into MySQL I can also get the correct data.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: MySQL needs to use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` and there are other settings -- provide the configuration.